# jQuery get() not triggering on click, no errors in console

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm banging my head against the wall here, and hoping I'm just blind to something obvious.

I have this DOM structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Lorem ipusm</h3>
        <p class="remove-story"><a href="http://example.com/remove/XX">Delete</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(".remove-story a").click(function()
    {
        var parent = $(this).closest('li');
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function()
        {
            $(parent).fadeOut();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

As it stands, clicking on the link within `.remove-story` does nothing, and the action triggered by the URL in the link does not occur either.

No JS errors pop-up in the console either on page load or when clicking the link.

If I remove the `$.get` function and simply fade out the list item, that works as expected.

If I visit the URL manually (or remove the `return false` and click the link), the link works and the back-end action completes (story removed).

Is there an error in my code here that anyone can spot? If not, any ideas as to where to look next to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you share the actual URL (not http://example.com) that you're using? When I run the code you gave, http://example.com is a 302 (redirect), and the callback function will only get called if the response is a 200. In your real application, is it possible that the request is going out, but the response is not a redirect, 404, or server error so the callback is not firing?

Comment: Following on from Emily's comment, is the URL on the same domain as the script? If not, you're probably coming up against the same origin policy.

Comment: Both good comments. James - the domains do indeed match. Emily - my network inspector shows the page loading as a 200 when I load it directly.

Comment: Actually James, you were right - the domain was the same, but I was loading the page over SSL, while making the ajax call unsecured, resulting in an origin policy error. Add as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your onclick with `$(document).ready(function() {})`:

```
$(".remove-story > a").click(function(e)
    {
        var parent = $(this).closest('li');
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function() {
                alert(12);
                $(parent).fadeOut();
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert('baaaahhhh:' + e);
            }
        })
         //e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }); 


​
```

Update: Changed `$.get` to `$.ajax` to see if thrs error while doing Ajax request.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, as it works as expected if $.get is removed

Comment: Change $.get to $.ajax to check if there is an error while doing ajax request.

Comment: Upvote for the code sample, but it turns out the issue was not my script, but to do with same origin policy (page was secured by the ajax call wasn't).

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly check if that get request really been send our, I mean using some tool like Fiddler or Chrome developer tool network tab, and then maybe add break point inside the call see if the **parent** you in that certain context is nothing or a wrong object

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your link `encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('href'));`

Here is a jsfiddle working:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Wnt8/

Comment: Nope, didn't do the trick. I've never had to use `encodeURIComponent` when working with jQuery and URLs.